# How to display log messages on console?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

I am using Spring and Hibernate in a stand alone application. i need to see logger messages on console as displayed below...

```
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DriverManagerDataSource [INFO] Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
2011-02-10 12:24:17 JdbcTemplate [DEBUG] Executing SQL statement [SELECT 1]
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DataSourceUtils [DEBUG] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DriverManagerDataSource [DEBUG] Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:/data/h2/testa]
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DataSourceUtils [DEBUG] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2011-02-10 12:24:17 JdbcTemplate [DEBUG] Executing SQL statement [SELECT 1]
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DataSourceUtils [DEBUG] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DriverManagerDataSource [DEBUG] Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:/data/h2/testa]
2011-02-10 12:24:17 DataSourceUtils [DEBUG] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

i have log4j properties file. what properties do i need to set to see the console as mentioned above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a console appender:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-12d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %p - %C{1}.%M(%-3L) | %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And then add it to the root:

```
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Comment: @jddsantaellam, Thanks for your reply. i need to see logs of spring and hibernate connection related things like when is connection opening and closing things in console . i have below config in my log4j.log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=DEBUG..............log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

Comment: You need to find out what package class does what you need and then activate DEBUG level for them. Probably debug the whole org.springframework is not a good idea. Be more accurate because you can get lost in logs.

Answer (score 0):

below i give you an example of a log4j configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %c (%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

then in the class that you want logging you need to declare the logger like this :

> private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Giannis.class);

and then you do something like

> logger.debug("Hello there");

you shoudl see this in the logs when the program is run

Answer (score 0):

From your comment looks like you have only one appender i.e. stdout and as you have asked to show on console you need to mention that appender in package definition like below.

```
log4j.log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, stdout   
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG, stdout    
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=DEBUG, stdout    
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache‌​.log4j.ConsoleAppender    
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=DEBUG     
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

It will print logs from 'org.hibernate', 'org.springframework', 'org.apache.axis' packages available at DEBUG level.

Note: If you want to capture logs only for specific package from spring/ hibernate you can mention that package with appender like below

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG, stdout
```